# How to control mac volume using python?

Tags: python, macos

I am trying to use gesture control to Control Volume on my MacOS in OpenCV. Since, pycaw can only be used for Windows, is there any alternative for macOS? I tried oascript but, it decreases the Frame Rate. Appreicate your help! Thank:)

```
import osascript

osascript.osascript("set volume output volume 100")
```

Comment: Decreases the framerate of what please? Your code doesn't seem to have have frames, or a rate.

Comment: yo the frames are literally as low as like 1 fps